# Has anyone successfully ripped a DVD using dvdbackup through a VM?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ffmpeg, fedora, dvd

Just looking for some help with ripping a DVD if you have some time to mess around with this. I'm running the following setup right now:

- Windows 10 64bit with all updates
- Oracle VM VirtualBox version 6.1
- Fedora server 31 VM
- dnf install -y libdvdcss dvdbackup ffmpeg

This exact setup works great on physical hardware, but ripping through the VM throws a bunch of read errors. The odd part is, some of the blocks copy without error. I can even concatenate the resulting VOB files into a somewhat watchable file, but of course it's all kinds of glitchy.

Here's the standard string I always use. Pretty straight forward:

```
dvdbackup --input=/dev/sr0 --error=m --feature --progress; eject -T
```

I also tried sharing the DVD drive in Windows and then mounting it in Fedora. Same result. Anybody got this to work? I also tried switching to VMWare Workstation Player, but no love there either.

Standard error you usually see with a dirty or scratched DVD:

```
padding 512 blocks
Copying Title, part 3/7: 88% done (906/1024 MiB)
Error reading VTS_03_3.VOB at block 1512416, read error returned
```

I presume you can't just copy the VOB files from the DVD to the computer. Windows and Fedora won't do it. It creates the files in the target folder, but they're like 64KB or 0KB sizes.

I know, why not just rip the DVD using the physical hardware, dummy? Well, my Fedora machine died and I'm out of spare parts right now to Frankenstein another box together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is your problem "VTS_03_3.VOB at block 1512416, read error returned" Looks like dvd has bad blocks for whatever reason.Does it rip on another PC ok? Can you straight copy the data off of the dvd?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different known-good DVDs. I ripped these on my physical box before it died with zero read errors. I could straight-copy the VOB files from the DVD, but then they play all jumbled because their not decrypted using the CSS library.

Comment: Convert the copied files from DVD, then see if you get errors.

Comment: Okay this is interesting. I'm wondering if we have a driver issue now. Here's what I tried:

`mkdir /root/cdrom/
mount /dev/sr0 /root/cdrom/
cp -v /root/cdrom/*VOB /root/`

Resulting error:
cp: error reading 'VTS_01_0.VOB': Input/output error

Comment: @Moab Let me try this. I'll copy the VOB files to the Windows desktop, move them to a shared folder, mount the shared folder in Fedora, concatenate the files into one VOB file, and then try ffmpeg. Might just work! LOL

Comment: @Moab That's a fail. Update added to top of thread - "I presume you can't just copy the VOB files from the DVD to the computer. Windows and Fedora won't do it. It creates the files in the target folder, but there like 64KB or 0KB sizes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like I am a dummy after all. I forgot to enable Pass-through on the virtual optical drive. It's working now. Thanks for your help @Moab!

[image: Screenshot showing Pass-through checkbox]